# Monotouch 4: App crash on launch on iPhone device, works on simulator

Tags: xamarin.ios

My setup is:

- MonoDevelop 2.8.5
- MonoTouch 4.0.6
- XCode 4.2

I create a Single-view iphone project. Building this works on both simulator and device.

Now I double click the .xib file, add a Textfield in XCode and create an outlet. No other code written.

Running this on the simulator works perfectly. Running it on any iPhone device crashes on launch. I managed to get the following stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MonoDevelop.Debugger.ObjectValueTreeView.SetValues (TreeIter parent, TreeIter it, System.String name, Mono.Debugging.Client.ObjectValue val) [0x0000d] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger/MonoDevelop.Debugger/ObjectValueTreeView.cs:640 
  at MonoDevelop.Debugger.ObjectValueTreeView.AppendValue (TreeIter parent, System.String name, Mono.Debugging.Client.ObjectValue val) [0x00034] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger/MonoDevelop.Debugger/ObjectValueTreeView.cs:627 
  at MonoDevelop.Debugger.ObjectValueTreeView.Refresh () [0x00091] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger/MonoDevelop.Debugger/ObjectValueTreeView.cs:468 
  at MonoDevelop.Debugger.ObjectValueTreeView.AddValue (Mono.Debugging.Client.ObjectValue value) [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger/MonoDevelop.Debugger/ObjectValueTreeView.cs:416 
  at MonoDevelop.Debugger.ExceptionCaughtDialog.Fill () [0x00084] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger/MonoDevelop.Debugger/ExceptionCaughtDialog.cs:82 
  at MonoDevelop.Debugger.ExceptionCaughtDialog.<HandleExceptionChanged>m__0 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger/MonoDevelop.Debugger/ExceptionCaughtDialog.cs:63 
  at Gtk.Application+InvokeCB.Invoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Timeout+TimeoutProxy.Handler () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Somebody mentioned that MonotTouch 4 only works with MonoDevelop 2.6. The problem is that I have already written a lot of code in MD 2.8.5 since the simulator was working, and when I roll back to MD 2.6 the project will not load...

Sorry for the missing formatting, I am new in stackoverflow

Any help is appreciated.
Themos

Comment: Here is a stacktrace from another iPhone:

    Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<AppDelegate 0x11a1d70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key xxx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an outlet in a XIB file that isn't mapped to a property in your controller in C#.  This is what the wonderful `class is not key value coding-compliant` message indicates.  [Here is a link](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/troubleshooting#This_class_is_not_key_value_coding-compliant_for_the_key_XXXX).

I would recommend getting the latest MonoTouch/MonoDevelop (non-beta) and XCode, then find what outlets you have and see which one is not hooked up properly.

You can manually set them up if XCode won't do it for you, there is a simple `[Outlet]` attribute you put on properties for outlets.  Look at a `*.designer.cs` file for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jonathan. However I don't think this is the case. I am using a Single-View iPhone project, and all I do is fire XCode, drag a Textfield on the view, then ctrl-drag to create the oulet, save and return to MD.

Now all I have is a view with a textfield in the middle, which runs correctly in the simulator, but crashes immediately on the actual device. The designer.cs file only has this: [Outlet]
  MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField testTextfield { get; set; }

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: I think most people are going to need more info to help.  Put a try-catch around your `static void Main` method, and hook into the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event writing any exceptions to the Console.  Then create the crash, while watching the console in XCode's Organizer, I think you can post a better stack trace from that.

Comment: Xamarin support was kind enough to send me a link with MT 4.0.7. I assume it was a problem with MT 4.0.6. Answer accepted as the description of the problem usually refers to that problem you mentioned.