# Monotouch default apps run in simulator but crash on device

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I've tried MT briefly with the simulator and decided to buy it along with joining the dev program.  Programs seem to work on the simulator but immediately crash on run when deployed to my (latest model running 5.1) iPad.  This is before doing anything!  Eg if I create a new ipad 'Utility' solution or 'Single view' application, change nothing from the generated defaults and run it on the simulator, it runs.  I then deploy it to the device, it installs but crashes out immediately on run.

The reported error is:

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<UIApplication 0x658ee0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view. 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29 
  at Utility.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/Mark/Projects/Utility/Utility/Main.cs:17
```

Line 17 in main.cs is: 
UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate"); 
The 'usings' etc are all present (this is the MT iPad 'Utility' solution unmodified).  I'm running what I believe is the latest xcode (no dev previews or anything) and monotouch versions under Lion.

Why would a default (but functional) app crash like this?  Is this trace info written to a file?  One other app I tried (the example 'shake me' GL drawing app) ran correctly on the device.

I see another question here: [Monotouch 4: App crash on launch on iPhone device, works on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702780/monotouch-4-app-crash-on-launch-on-iphone-device-works-on-simulator) which ended up being a bug in monotouch, but I've got the latest version.

Thanks for your help guys, really appreciate it.

Mark

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not Key Value Coding Compliant (Monotouch and iOS 6)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574444/not-key-value-coding-compliant-monotouch-and-ios-6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One place where I have personally seen this error before is:

http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/135125-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-xxxx

> This error occurs when you have initialized a ViewController in code but also have the ViewController initialized from a XIB file.
>
> This could happen if you have the "Main Interface" value set to a ViewController you're creating in code. To resolve this issue, make this value empty, then no ViewController will be initialized automatically.

Can you check your pInfo file to see if there is a MainInterface set?

If this is a bug in the default project templates, then please also file a report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi

Comment: Thanks for that.  I did have one set, but going via that support I ended up finding some other OS updates and such that have solved much of my issue.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: THANK GOD!
Finally! I solved it by opening the info.plist and remove the value I had selected in the main interface drop.!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have at least MonoTouch 5.2.4 version and you write to the console in your code, you need to update to solve the crash.

Comment: Thanks, I had the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was when build using Storyboard, I found the way to fix it with that:

Right-click your project, select 'Options' then 'iOS Build' under the 'Build' sub-heading, add -f to 'Additional mtouch arguments' and rebuild.

This solution is not mine, all thanks to Richard Adams, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583923/1600491