# This class is not key value coding-compliant (with storyboard)

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm just getting started in iOS development with Xamarin and seem to have hit a road block. I'm trying to create a custom table cell to display some data. So taking prompts from various online sources (see [here](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html) for example), I created a .xib file deleted the view that Xamarin automatically created and replaced it with a `UITableViewCell`. I added a few labels to my cell, I registered my cell with `RegisterNibForCellReuse` and set up my class that inherits from `UITableViewSource` to return my custom cell when appropriate. So far so good.

The problem starts when I take any of the controls in my custom cell and try to create an outlet. In XCode create the outlet and everything looks okay. Back in Xamarin I can see it's automagically created a property for it.

```
[Register ("MyCustomCell")]
partial class MyCustomCell
{
    [Outlet]
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel MyLabel { get; set; }



    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
    {
        if (MyLabel != null) {
            MyLabel.Dispose ();
            MyLabel = null;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try and run the code I get a runtime error saying `This class in not key value coding-compliant for key the key MyOutlet`

Any idea what might be happening? The Xamarin docs suggests a possible cause [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting), but I'm not sure it's relevant. I don't see anything like that in *any* of the designer files Xamarin has created and they've all been fine. I tried replacing the property definition above with one that uses the `Connect` attribute instead of `Outlet` and uses `GetNativeField` and `SetNativeField`, but I see the same result.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this problem for a while in my case it turned out to be a problem relating to the build process.  The following fixed it for me :

Right-click your project, select 'Options' then 'iOS Build' under the 'Build' sub-heading, add -f to 'Additional mtouch arguments' and rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same issue, and finally I did Product->Clean within XCode, and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click your project, select 'Options' then 'iOS Build' under the 'Build' sub-heading, add -f to 'Additional mtouch arguments' and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was creating actions for a few buttons, and I accidentally made an outlet, instead of an action. I just deleted the @IBOutlet line.

My error was:

```
 this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Button_Twitter_Clicked.'
```

Again, in my case, I found my solution from:

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/52021/how-do-i-fix-the-issue-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-in-xcode-6/

```
 - Click the "Show Find Navigator" on the left hand side
 - Search for the key above that gave the error, in my case it was the "Button_Twitter_Clicked" key.
 - Double click on the result (my case, I clicked on the View Controller:Outlet
 - On the right hand side, find the Key that was in the exception thrown during runtime (Has exclamation mark)
   (States that the view controller does not have an outlet named [outletname]
 - Click the X button
 - Recompile :)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Richard's answer.

Another thing you can do is Rebuild the project. Is what the -f argument does.