# Using segues with custom table cell

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, segue, xamarin

I have a custom cell type that I've defined completely in code (subclassing UITableViewCell) because [I can't get it to work using a xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941157/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-with-storyboard). I can add it to a cell in a table in my storyboard and it displays just fine. However, I want to have selecting that cell trigger a segue to another screen. I can create the segue in the storyboard in xcode, but it doesn't seem to actually work when I run the code (i.e. nothing happens, the cell is just selected). I also have a regular title/subtitle cell in the same table that has a separate segue to a different screen and that one works just fine (touching that cell loads the next page as expected), so it seems to be a problem specifically with the custom cell. I suspect that something in the custom cell is replacing the attached segues.

So how do I make sure my custom cell can use the segues defined in the storyboard?

Comment: Have you called the _performSegueWithIdentifier_ method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set an ID to your segue in the storyboard, and in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegueID"];`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Which class would have `didSelectRowAt`? I found `RowSelected` in the UITableViewController, the same place I have my `PrepareForSegue`. I added some code there to call `PerformSegue` but it seems that `RowSelected` never gets called.

Comment: It is a `UITableViewDelegate` method, should be implemented in your `UITableViewController` subclass. Here is a [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) with that delegate.

Comment: That doesn't seem to quite map to xamarin classes. But there's a `RowSelected` in the `UITableViewSource` that does seem to get called and I set up an event which I can subscribe to from the `UITableViewController` to call `PerformSegue`. Doesn't quite seem right, but appears to work.