# Xamarin iOS Simulator Showing Black Screen

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I am running 2015 Visual Studio with Xamarin.  When I launch the iOS Simulator, it is showing a black screen on the simulator.  I am using a Storyboard with a Navigation Controller.

- I have the Main Interface set to the my storyboard.
- Size Class - Any / Any
- I have restarted the simulator, ran "Reset Content and Settings"

AppDelegate code (only method with contents.):

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        // If you have defined a root view controller, set it here:
        Window.RootViewController = new Controllers.RegistrationController();
        // make the window visible
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
        return true;
    }
```

[image: My Storyboard]

Comment: Can you add your AppDelegate code too ?Also you may try setting a breakpoint in Appdelegate to verify if it is being invoked.

Comment: Code Added above, that was all that had code in.

Comment: Is FinishedLaunching getting invoked ?

Comment: Is this only happening with vs?  Have you tried with xamarin studio on the Mac?

Comment: Do you mean by launching the simulator the app or the simulator?

Comment: Do you have a launch screen image?

Comment: I start the Debug process from Visual Studio which starts the Simulator on the Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like :

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    // create a new window instance based on the screen size
    Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

    string storyboardName = "Main";
    UIStoryboard storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName(storyboardName, null);
    // if it is the first viewcontroller
    UIViewController vc = storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController(); 

    // If you have defined a root view controller, set it here:
    Window.RootViewController = vc;
    // make the window visible
    Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
    return true;
}
```

if your storyboard is called Main.stroyboard try using this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    return true;
}
```

I tested both of these options and both should work when your Storyboard is called Main

Comment: Are you putting this in the FinishedLaunching event?

Comment: The Navigation Controller is supposed to be the Initial View Controller, right?  I have my ViewController set as the Root Controller.  I added an image of my storyboard above.

Comment: Is your storyboard called Main.storyboard? And yes it should be

Comment: Yes, it is called Main.storyboard.

Comment: Just edited my post could you try the second suggestion it may sound weird but please try it.

Comment: I got the following error which is identifying the button on the ViewController.  Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<UIViewController 0x7a7bd530> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btnRegister.

Comment: That is great! Because this is a different problem so we are one step further! Can you clean your project and try it again?

Comment: I had a Touch Up Inside event, but when I click off of the button and onto the storyboard in the Designer, I lose it.  So I currently don't have any events on the button.

Comment: Could you try the things they suggest here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11750/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key

Comment: Clean doesn't fix it.  The designer.cs for the viewcontroller.cs looks fine.  I don't see anything duplicated there.

Comment: Did you also delete the obj and bin folders? Sometimes a normal clean is not enough.

Comment: When you click on the button and the in the properties windows do you see any events? If so remove them and also remove them in your code if you have those

Comment: Are they also removed in your designer.cs file?

Comment: Yup, I checked that they were gone there as well.

Comment: Just to see if we can get something running for you. Try adding a new navigation controller to the storyboard and set that one as the initial viewcontroller.

Comment: Or try these options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941157/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-with-storyboard

Comment: The -f and the link all assemblies doesn't change anything.

Comment: I removed the button and now it errors on a label control on the view with the same error.

Comment: Interesting, I get the same black screen when I am trying to run the Multi screen Phone app that you can down load from Xamarin.

Comment: could you try this adding a new navigation controller to the storyboard and set that one as the initial viewcontroller and ignore the ones you have for now

Comment: Try moving the stuff you had to the new ones that should fix your problem and your question is answerd now I right?

Comment: I discovered that you need to add the controller before you start giving your controls names.

Comment: Thanks I will remember that next time I see this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a segue from your UINavigationController to an UIViewController with the content in it. If you don't have a segue then your app is going to show a black screen since the app doesn't think it has any content.

If I understand you correctly, your storyboard may look like this: [Storyboard 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OHI3.png)

And you need to create a segue between the two view controllers so that your storyboard looks like this with the segue-arrow between the two view controllers: [Storyboard 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Q2X.png)

Comment: I have a Seque going from the Navigation Controller to the View Controller

Comment: I added an image of my story board.

Comment: @Adam Why do you need code in your AppDelegate FinishedLaunching? Usually you just use "return true" in the FinishedLaunching function, i.e. when your storyboard is called Main.storyboard.

Comment: Try to Clean, Rebuild and remove the app in the simulator and run the app again.

Comment: That doesn't work.  I also ran "Reset Content and Settings" on the Simulator.

Comment: You said in a comment that you had an event on the button but then you deleted it, check that your event is deleted in the storyboard and in the designer also. Also check that your btnRegister exists in the designer.cs. Also check if your view controller has the right class connected to it.

Comment: I didn't delete the event, but when I click off of the button onto the storyboard and then click back onto the button, the event isn't there on the button anymore.